# TPS54260 DC-DC Buck Regulator BOOT and PH pin voltage drop

Tags: voltage, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck, output

I am using [TPS54260](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvsa86d/slvsa86d.pdf) Buck converter which steps down 16V to 5V output.

Load current is 600mA max.

To the inrush current through the output inductor, I did some rework. But after some rework, my 5V output is oscillating as shown below.

[image]

Upon inspection, we found the voltage between BOOT and PH pin to be 0.76V.

But in another Board which is working fine (getting stable +5V output), we get the voltage between BOOT and PH pin to be 6.081V.

From the datasheet, Section 7.3.4, page 13, we find this

> " When the voltage from BOOT to PH drops below 2.1 V, the high-side
>   MOSFET is turned off using an UVLO circuit which allows the low-side
>   diode to conduct and refresh the charge on the BOOT capacitor. Since
>   the supply current sourced from the BOOT capacitor is low, the
>   high-side MOSFET can remain on for more switching cycles than are
>   required to refresh the capacitor, thus the effective duty cycle of
>   the switching regulator is high."

I know this has happened due to some improper rework. But can someone tell what might have caused for this to happen and can someone please provide a simple explanation of blockquote operation in simple terms

Comment: you need to show all design changes ,looks like its motor-boating  low f oscillation

Comment: Design changes in the sense? I have not changed my design

Comment: Why rework? Then

Comment: @Newbie Not only it is oscillating but also around half the expected output voltage. Could you please tell us more what are the reworks you've done?

Comment: I am sorry. Rework meaning, I just lifted the inductor from its pad and inserted a wire loop between the inductor pad and one terminal of the inductor so as to measure the inductor inrush current during the start-up